# Developing admin interface for Apache Lucene

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I've developed an app that uses Lucene engine to search. Now I want to develop an admin interface more or less similar to the one in Solr.

I need to interface to include some basic configuration, status report, job manager and maybe even to run some example searches on Lucene's index.

I am thinking if I should develop it from scratch or somehow use some of the code in Solr. I was wondering if anyone knows what framework was used to develop it (if any at all) and where  I can find the admin interface code.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the reason you need one? And why dont Solr (and ElasticSearch) satisfy you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to write admin panel from scratch. The reason is solr admin code seems to be coupled with underlaying solr implementation , though you can access the other lucene index from solr panel , to get better control over your lucene configuration you should prefer writing your wrapper like solr , also if you write your own wrapper , you can even have better control than solr have on itself ,reason being if at later point of time you want your lucene index build and search configurable using Web interface it will work seamlessly because programmatic configuration will just about writing a service layer on top of lucene.

Hope my answer helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are building an admin interface for lucene index, why not just use Solr which will give you a lot of flexibility ?
Solr works on the underlying Lucene Index.
So you can still create the index using lucene and use Solr admin interface to help you interact with the index, instead of trying to build a new one.
Surely you would need to design your schema inline with with lucene implementation.

Comment: I was considering this of course, but decided eventually to go with lucene directly because i needed to make a lot of changes and using solr was more overhead than using lucene only

Comment: Thats odd. Cause Solr would be the more easier option providing you the flexibility, accessibility and maintainability instead of core lucene. You can always Customize Solr and extend it to your needs unless you are using some features of core lucene not yet supported by Solr. Just my Opinion.